# IPython Notebook can't import numpy package (even though Anaconda is being used)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/cs109/content/blob/master/HW0.ipynb) iPython notebook from the CS 109 Big Data class from Harvard. I installed Anaconda and when trying to import the numpy package (when running the second box of the mentioned .ipynb file) I receive the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-372b34474489> in <module>()
  4 
  5 # Numpy is a library for working with Arrays
----> 6 import numpy as np
  7 print "Numpy version:        %6.6s (need at least 1.7.1)" % np.__version__
  8
```

This is confusing given that I thought Anaconda had numpy out of the box. The numpy package is actually installed in the pkgs folder inside the Anaconda folder in my computer. Should I be running the .ipynb file from a specific folder in order to Anaconda to be able to import numpy?

**I should not that when importing numpy in Spyder it does work. I am confused about why is this happening.**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the version is incompatible. Maybe just double check that you have the most recent version installed using `conda update numpy` and if this doesn't work:  `conda install numpy`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but did not work. I have the latest numpy version 1.8.2 Might the problem be related that the HW0.ipynb file is in C:\Users\username\Anaconda? Should it be instead in C:\Users\username\Anaconda\Scripts?

Comment: I really have now idea about how Anaconda works on Windows, but on Linux and Mac OS you can run it from wherever you want. Typically, you won't put it in the anaconda dir though. Just try to run it from your desktop.

Comment: What happens btw if you just start up a new blank ipython notebook and try to import numpy?